# Sort blocks of data

Tags: bash

I have the following blocks of data:

```
<item>
    <link>test</link>
    <guid>test</guid>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <pubDate>Fri, 19 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC</description>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test2</link>
    <guid>test2</guid>
    <title>ABC2</title>
    <pubDate>Tue, 13 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC2</description>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test3</link>
    <guid>test3</guid>
    <title>ABC3</title>
    <pubDate>Tue, 07 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC3</description>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test4</link>
    <guid>test4</guid>
    <title>ABC4</title>
    <pubDate>Tue, 13 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC4</description>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test5</link>
    <guid>test5</guid>
    <title>ABC5</title>
    <pubDate>Thu, 08 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC5</description>
</item>
```

I am looking for a way to sort the blocks by date (*pubDate*); unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this at the moment. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The tool `xq` might be able to help you along.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Are you referring to [this xq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq#xml-support) ?

Comment: This is, of course, invalid XML since there is no root node...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Decorate/Sort/Undecorate idiom with any awk, sort, and cut:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS="[<>]"; OFS="\t" }
    {
        lines[++numLines] = $0
        tag = $2
    }
    tag == "pubDate" {
        split($3,d,/[, ]+/)
        mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",d[3]) + 2) / 3
        ts = sprintf("%04d %02d %02d %8s %5s", d[4], mthNr, d[2], d[5], d[6])
    }
    tag == "/item" {
        recNr++
        for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++ ) {
            print ts, recNr, lineNr, lines[lineNr]
        }
        numLines = 0
    }
' "${@:--}" |
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n |
cut -f4-
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
<item>
    <link>test3</link>
    <guid>test3</guid>
    <title>ABC3</title>
    <pubDate>Tue, 07 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC3</description>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test5</link>
    <guid>test5</guid>
    <title>ABC5</title>
    <pubDate>Thu, 08 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC5</description>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test2</link>
    <guid>test2</guid>
    <title>ABC2</title>
    <pubDate>Tue, 13 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC2</description>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test4</link>
    <guid>test4</guid>
    <title>ABC4</title>
    <pubDate>Tue, 13 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC4</description>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test</link>
    <guid>test</guid>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <pubDate>Fri, 19 Jun 2023 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>ABC</description>
</item>
```